# divs shrink when viewed in chromebook; font-size does not

Tags: css, chromebook

I am wondering why when I view my website (and all websites) on a chromebook 11.6in screen, the entire website shrinks.

Specifically, I have a div that is 960px wide that contains words that are 12px in size. This looks fine in every regular sized computer I have viewed it on. However, when I view it on a chromebook, the 960px div appears smaller. In fact every div is a bit smaller. This is fine, however, the text no longer fits into this smaller div and spills outside of its containing div.

And idea why this is happening? And how would I go about fixing this?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use viewport settings in your meta. Mozilla has a great post about using the viewport

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag